# Suppress !!python/unicode in YAML output

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

When dumping (ruamel.yaml, PyYAML) the dict `data = {'abc': 'def'}`
 as YAML (with `default_flow_style=False`) in Python 2.7 you will get:

```
abc: def
```

which is fine. However if you make all strings unicode (by `u` prefixing or by using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`) this gets dumped as:

```
!!python/unicode 'abc': !!python/unicode 'def'
```

How can I dump all strings (unicode prefixed or not) without tag, without reverting to using `safe_dump()`? Adding `allow_unicode=True` doesn't do the trick.

Complete example that generates the unwanted tags:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {'abc': 'def'}
ruamel.yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a different representer that handles the `unicode` to `str` conversion:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def my_unicode_repr(self, data):
    return self.represent_str(data.encode('utf-8'))

ruamel.yaml.representer.Representer.add_representer(unicode, my_unicode_repr)

data = {'abc': u'def'}
ruamel.yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False)
```

gives:

```
abc: def
```

for PyYAML, this works as well, just replace `ruamel.yaml` by `yaml`